# Result not simplified

Tags: simplifying-expressions

The following script gives not the simplest result. What should be the right command to get the simplest result?

```
f[x_, y_, a_, b_] := x (a/b)^(y/x b)
g[x_, y_, a_, b_] := Log[f[x, y, a, b]]*x
TraditionalForm[Simplify[g[x, y, a, b]]]
```

resulting in:

x log(x (a/b)^((b y)/x))

Comment: Append `// PowerExpand // Expand` after your result, if the variables and parameters are real valued. the function g[_] is not defined

Comment: your `g` is `f` ?  with this change, Mathematica does not think `x log(x (a/b)^((b y)/x))` is correct result. You can use `Reduce` to check.

Comment: @Andreas: I have corrected the typo. Your procedure gives $by \log(a)-by \log(a) + ... $ How do I then factor the terms?

Comment: MMA version 12.1 gives: `x log(x^2 (a (-y)+a+b y))`

Comment: I get `2 x Log[x] + x Log[a - a y + b y]` which doesn't leave much room for further simplification.

Comment: @Andreas: I am so very sorry. I typed the wrong formula for $f$. Please check again.

Comment: @Nasser:  I am so very sorry. I typed the wrong formula for $f$. Please check again.

Comment: @DanielHuber:  I am so very sorry. I typed the wrong formula for $f$. Please check again.

Comment: Try: `PowerExpand[g[x, y, a, b]] // Simplify // TraditionalForm`

Comment: Append `// PowerExpand // Expand // FullSimplify`